# MS Access Not Importing Hyperlink Address

Tags: excel, import, hyperlink, ms-access-2010

I have an Access database that I feed from a series of Excel import documents. One of the docs imports info that includes a hyperlink. When it imports, it only imports the "Text to Display", the "Address" is left blank. See images below.
This is what Access shows:

[image]

This is what the excel import shows:

[image]

You can see that the Address from the Excel import on the bottom, did not bring in the address. Only the text to display.

So my question is how can I import a hyperlink and have it bring both the Text to Display and the address?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, I was able to answer this question myself. In the export document, with the field that you want to be the hyperlink, it should be created in the following format:

```
Text To Display + Hashtag + Address
```

So as an example

```
ABC123#www.abc123.com
```

Once you import this, what is before the hashtag will be the text displayed in Access, and what's after the hashtag will be the address of the hyperlink. Assuming you've formatted the Access field as a hyperlink, that should be all you need to import a hyperlink and have it work properly.